# Format scientific notation in R

Tags: r, numbers, format

I have a number which show as

```
a <- 1.34467773e-5.
```

I want to format it to

```
a <- 1.34e-5.
```

How can I do it?

Thanks.

Comment: `options(digits=3)`

Comment: options() change the global options which might not be good for every situation, for example, I only want the p-values to be displayed in the scientific notation and other numbers in the default way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
formatC(a, format = "e", digits = 2)
```

Comment: It's unclear in the question if the desired output is `numeric` or `character`, this is the latter. G5W's comment is the former.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the function `sprintf`. For example:

```
sprintf("%.1e", 0.00008765)
```